# How to stop UIPanGestureRecognizer from recognizing taps

Tags: objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, segue

On one of the UIViewControllers of my iPhone app, I have a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached so that when the user swipes to the left or to the right the app advances or goes back one screen.  However, the problem is that when the user taps (rather than swipes) on the screen it still advances.  How can I stop this from happening.  I have pasted the relevant code below:

```
-(void) addGestureRecognizer
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;
    pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRecognized:)];
    [pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

-(void) swipeRecognized: (UIPanGestureRecognizer  *) recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) return;
    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
    if(velocity.x > 0)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        @try
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:NEXT_STEP_SEGUE sender:self];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception)
        {
            //Silently die...muhaha
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` for swipes. Is there a particular reason you're use a pan?

With a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` you can specify for which direction it should recognize the gesture.

It's also better for your users, to use the appropriate gestures. That way, they'll feel right at home :)

Comment: I'm using it so that I can detect 1 or 2 finger swipes as well as swipes in either direction

Comment: UISwipeGestureRecognizers also has a property called `numberOfTouchesRequired`. And you can easily add two recognizers, one for each direction. I would really urge you to use the appropriate gestures. In your solution, a finger moving 1 mm would trigger the pan, but that's hardly a swipe...

Comment: What exactly is the difference between a UISwipeGestureRecognizer and a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: One is for swipes...a quick flick in a single direction, and one is for pans...a continuous dragging motion that can change direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, as suggested by fguchelaar, or use the `translationInView:` method to figure out how far the user has actually moved the finger (for taps, that should be near zero).

You also shouldn't return early if the state is not `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` (first line in your method), otherwise your method will only get called once, when the gesture begins, but not during the gesture. If that's what you actually want, a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is all you need. The benefit of the pan gesture recognizer is mostly that you can track the user's finger and provide direct feedback (like moving the view while the finger is still down).